# How to gather data from a file and execute a Python file using it via right click?

Tags: python

This title is a bit confusing but let me explain. So say you have a file called test.txt. If you right click on it, it will most likely have a menu appear and will say stuff like "Open in Notepad". How can I get a python file to show in that menu so that it could say "Open in program.py" and the program would run and for example

```
print(data)
input()
```

Data being the contents of test.txt. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the registry entries in Windows. See [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) to how.

You have to replace the path with your own script such as `C:\\Program Files\\Something\\YourPythonScript %1`

%1 represents the associated file name.

Edit: In your python script, you can use sys.argv in order to retrieve the file name of the associated file and process on it.

```
import sys
#Get selected file
filename = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but for completeness am thinking @ItzWillPower may also want to understand parsing the file for the data, so will need to read the command line argument (using something like argparse: https://pymotw.com/3/argparse/ ) and then read that in for the data

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the suggestion. Edited the answer to show how to get selected file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use other programs to open your foo.py python code. but that program can't execute the code directly just by one click right. you have to open in program that can run python codes and run the code there.
hope this help you.